# Swift, core data and Int16 addition problem

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4

I have an app that is working well with Swift and Core Data. However, I'm having 1 problem with it. For the most part it works fine adding prizes, however when I try to add 2 large prizes in a row, it crashes where the prizes are added to the users total. Can anyone give me some guidance on this? Thanks in advance.
Here is my User object.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension User {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<User> {
        return NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: Int16
    @NSManaged public var name: String
    @NSManaged public var pulls: Int16
    @NSManaged public var played: Bool
    @NSManaged public var pullsUsed: Int16
    @NSManaged public var pullsLeft: Int16
    @NSManaged public var totalWon: Int16
    @NSManaged public var lastName: String
}
```

And here is where it crashes. I pass in a currentUser which is fetched from Core Data. I pass in a currentScore. It crashes on the last line, but only when the currentScore exceeds 4 digits.
It seems to be a problem with adding Int16s. The crash just says Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1044b60bc).

```
    func scoreFromUser(currentUser: User, currentScore: Int16) {
        currentUser.pullsLeft -= 1
        currentUser.pullsUsed += 1
        let total: Int16 = currentUser.totalWon
        let newTotal: Int16 = total + currentScore
        currentUser.totalWon = newTotal
    }
```

Comment: Probably integer overflow.  Is there any reason you're not using `Int` instead of `Int16`?

Comment: I'm using Int16 because it's saved in Core Data which doesn't have Int as an option. My options are Int16, Int32 and Double.

Comment: Try `Int32` then.  `Int16` maxes out at `32767`.

Comment: Ah! That totally makes sense for this particular bug. Duh!